# Ejecutar sentencia si se produce cualquier excepción

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones

Esto no es un problema que tengo, si no una duda 'didáctica'. Me pregunto si existe alguna forma de hacer que una combinación de `try` - `except` y/o `else` o `finally` ejecuten un bloque de código solo si ocurriese una excepción.
Las instrucciones `else` y `finally` hacen es lo contrario, ejecutan el bloque si no ocurre excepción o bien en cualquier caso.

Ejemplo

```
try:
    raise ValueError('var')
    print('Proceso ejecutado correctamente')
except ValueError:
    print('Error, hay un valor incorrecto')
except TypeError:
    print('El tipo de datos es incorrecto')
except:
    print('Error. Ha ocurrido un error desconocido')
else:
    print('Este bloque ejecuta solo si no hay excepciones')
finally:
    print('Este bloque ejecuta siempre')
```

La salida del código anterior:

```
Error, hay un valor incorrecto
Este bloque ejecuta siempre
```

Y si se comenta el `raise`

```
Proceso ejecutado correctamente
Este bloque ejecuta solo si no hay excepciones
Este bloque ejecuta siempre
```

Lo que quiero es que independientemente de la excepción, se imprimiera otro mensaje que se sume al de las excepciones, por ejemplo: "*Contacte con el administrador del sistema*".

Sin `raise` o comentado

```
Proceso ejecutado correctamente
```

Con `raise ValueError('var')`

```
Error, hay un valor incorrecto
Contacte con el administrador del sistema
```

Poniendo un `raise ZeroDivisionError('var')`

```
Error. Ha ocurrido un error desconocido
Contacte con el administrador del sistema
```

Claro, sé que esto se puede resolver colocando el mismo mensaje redundantemente dentro de todos los `excepts`; O bien otra forma es con una *señal*, que si no se actualiza desde el `try` entonces al salir de las sentencias añadirle el otro mensaje. Pero la idea es hacerlo dentro del bloque `try - except`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posiblemente una "*bandera*" sea la opción más limpia y eficiente para el caso, pero una forma de resolver el problema propuesto puede ser:

```
try:
    raise ValueError('var')
    print('Proceso ejecutado correctamente')
except:
    try:
        raise
    except ValueError:
        print('Error, hay un valor incorrecto')
    except TypeError:
        print('El tipo de datos es incorrecto')
    except:
        print('Error. Ha ocurrido un error desconocido')
    finally:
        print('Contacte con el administrador del sistema')
```

Si ocurriese una excepción, entrará en el segundo `try-except` anidado, el cual siempre va a ejecutar el `finally` y se mostrará el segundo mensaje.

> Error, hay un valor incorrecto 
>   Contacte con el administrador del sistema

Referencia: [How to execute something if any exception happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151561/how-to-execute-something-if-any-exception-happens)